# X doesn't start automatically, startx works fine

Tags: x11, manjaro, lxdm

I've been using lxdm for a long time, but today after upgrading manjaro, the x doesn't started automatically.

the `journalctl -u lxdm` output:

```
-- Reboot --
Dec 22 10:16:35 localhost systemd[1]: Started LXDE Display Manager.
```

the `systemctl status lxdm` output:

```
● lxdm.service - LXDE Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lxdm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-12-22 10:16:35 WIB; 4min 19s ago
 Main PID: 565 (lxdm-binary)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/lxdm.service
           ├─565 /usr/sbin/lxdm-binary
           └─574 /usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg -background none :0 vt01 -nolisten tcp -novtswitch -auth /var/run/lxdm/lxdm-:0.auth

Dec 22 10:16:35 localhost systemd[1]: Started LXDE Display Manager.
```

the config `/etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf` is never change since beginning

```
[base]
## uncomment and set autologin username to enable autologin
# autologin=dgod

## uncomment and set timeout to enable timeout autologin,
## the value should >=5
# timeout=10

## default session or desktop used when no systemwide config
session=/usr/bin/startxfce4

## uncomment and set to set numlock on your keyboard
# numlock=0

## set this if you don't want to put xauth file at ~/.Xauthority
# xauth_path=/tmp

# not ask password for users who have empty password
# skip_password=1

## greeter used to welcome the user
greeter=/usr/lib/lxdm/lxdm-greeter-gtk

[server]
## arg used to start xserver, not fully function
arg=/usr/bin/X -background vt1
# uncomment this if you really want xserver listen to tcp
# tcp_listen=1
# uncoment this if you want reset the xserver after logou
# reset=1

[display]
## gtk theme used by greeter
gtk_theme=Adwaita

## background of the greeter
# bg=/usr/share/backgrounds/default.png

## if show bottom pane
bottom_pane=1

## if show language select control
lang=1

## if show keyboard layout select control
keyboard=0

## the theme of greeter
theme=Industrial

[input]

[userlist]
## if disable the user list control at greeter
disable=0

## whitelist user
white=

## blacklist user
black=
```

What could possibly wrong?

Comment: You need to look at the system logs (I don't know which file specifically on Manjaro).

Answer (score -1):

Uncommenting the `lxdm.conf`'s solves this issue, but still this less secure way

```
autologin=yourusername
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? Starting X and logging in are not the same thing.

Comment: that parameter makes the x started automatically